# (Friday Night Funkin) running lime test windows

Tags: powershell, window, lime, haxelib

Whenever I run the command lime test window on Windows PowerShell to build my game for fnf, it says "You must have a "project.xml" file or specify another valid project file when using the 'test' command."

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the project.xml file several times like this:

project.xml to Project.xml or Project.xml to project.xml

I had this issue before.